# how i can add input type property the same like a name value this input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following input fields:

```
<form id="validate">
        <input name="name" value="" validate-required />
        <input name="email" value="" validate-required validate-email/>
        <input name="date" value="" validate-date/>
        <input name="ip" value="" validate-regexp="^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

And I need to add a type value for every field the same, like a name value, but with jQuery.

So far I've tried this :

```
$(":not(input[type=submit])").prop("type", ????); I don't know what I must write on ???? place.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(":not(input[type=submit])").prop("type", function (i, p) { return this.name; });
```

Note that this doesn't check if the type you're setting it with is valid. See this for more details [jQuery.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function).

Comment: this is exactly what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make every input of the same type such as : text , use the following code.

```js
$(":not(input[type=submit])").prop("type", $(this).val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="validate">
  <input name="name" value="" validate-required />
  <input name="email" value="" validate-required validate-email/>
  <input name="date" value="" validate-date/>
  <input name="ip" value="" validate-regexp="^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

For other inputs in your code you could also use the following input types that are supported in HTML5 as well :

> text,date,datetime,email,url,datetime-local

A list of all possible input type attribute values is given : [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp)

Comment: yea I know it, but I need to add a type-value automatically,  and the same like name-value

Comment: @RomanFedyshyn : Check my updated code, I've edited it to automatically add a type which is the same as the value of that input.